# How can i remove special character from a variable using perl

Tags: perl, unix

This is my sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$file = SUN;
$file1 = abc.$file.cde
print "Value is : $file1\n"
```

I want Output like this abcSUNcde
What regular expression need for this.

Comment: 1) You should always use use `use strict; use warnings;`. 1a) You should always declare your variables. (`use strict;` will force you). 1b) You shouldn't rely on unquoted words being treated as strings. (`use strict;` will force you to quote them)

Comment: 2) You are missing semi-colons `;`. With these, your program actually does output `abcSUNcde`. I don't see what "special characters" you want removed or what regular expressions have to do with anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well [`ikegami`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) said in his comment you are missing the semicolons at the end of the line (terminating the line or line should be ended).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$file = SUN;
$file1 = "abc${file}cde";
print "Value is : $file1\n";
```

This is will print `abcSUNcde` as an output of your code.

In case if you want to remove the special characters (`what I understand except keyboarding characters`)

```
$file2=~s/[^A-Za-z]//g;
```

Let try this and modify as well you can.

Comment: `A-z` is a rather strange character range to choose. I suspect you meant `A-Za-z`.

Comment: @ikegami: I couldn't understand `(` `)`

Comment: `(` and `)` are found between `A` and `z`. (But you've changed it)